# QMYSQL driver not loaded in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mysql-connector

I am struggling with PyQt5 project which uses QMYSQL driver. I have placed qsqlite.dll and libmysql.dll (not sure if this one is needed) inside site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers

Moreover, I put copy of mentioned files inside folder in which I have my python executable file, and it still doesn't works. Below code returns error "Driver not loaded". I spent too much time on it, please help if you have any ideas.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QCheckBox, QLabel, \
QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QTableWidget, \
QFrame, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QStackedLayout, QHeaderView, QSpacerItem, QLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import * 
import sys
import mysql.connector
import PyQt5


class Window(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        
        c = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        c.setDatabaseName("name")
        c.setHostName('localhost')
        c.setUserName('root')
        c.setPassword('mypassword')
        c.open()
        
        if not c.open():
            QMessageBox.critical(None,
            "Error!",
            "Database Error: %s" % c.lastError().databaseText(),
            )
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print("Opened")

def main():
    print(PyQt5.__path__)
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried placing driver file in different directories but it didn't help. It is not added to the PATH variable but I don't think this is the case.

**UPDATE**

As I am still struggeling with this, now I want to build MySQL plugin for Windows by myself.

I am following guidance from official source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html

```
mkdir build-sqldrivers
cd build-sqldrivers

qt-cmake -G Ninja <qt_installation_path>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<qt_installation_path>\<platform> -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\lib\libmysql.lib"
cmake --build .
cmake --install .
```

unfortunately, I see the error: **'qt-cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I installed CMake and added cmake.exe directory to the PATH. Still the same error. I also added CMakeLists.txt to that folder.

Please advise what should I do. I don't understand difference between qt-cmake and cmake. I was trying to find qt-cmake on my files but it seems its not there.

My Qt was installed with PyQt5. I wonder if that was not sufficient as maybe qt-cmake was not part of installed package?

Comment: How did you get the .dll, is it a version for msvc?

Comment: @eyllanesc I actually took it from source on internet, which somebody advised as it helped him to resolve exact the same problem. But it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: my question is accurate, was the .dll compiled using msvc? since there is also a mysql .dll compiled with mingw

Comment: @eyllanesc .dll was not complied using msvc and I don't know how to do that. Maybe it is easier to build my own MySQL plugin. Please kindly see my new post.